# SELECT DISTINCT RECENT VALUE FROM DB

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get all distinct value from db according to their recent/last `entryModTime`.

For your understanding

```
id entry_modtime

3  13-12-1977
3  14-12-1977
4  13-12-1977
5  13-12-1977 
2  13-12-1977
3  15-12-1977
```

In the above table `id` field is not primary. I need get all data from that table so the output should be,

```
3 15-12-1977
4 13-12-1977
5 13-12-1977
2 13-12-1977
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group` around your `id` and select the highest date for every `id` with `max()`

```
select id, max(entry_modtime) as latest_entry_modtime
from your_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, max(entry_modtime)
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: You can't mix aggregate functions and normal column selects without a group.

Comment: Yes, but how does it differ from my answer I gave 7 minutes ago?